# How can I create a boxplot with whiskers?

Tags: r, boxplot, errorbar

I have created a plot with 3 boxplots, but my whiskers are not showing for one of them.

[image: Boxplot]

How can I make them show?

This is my data:

> Class 3: 5.055052 3.028838 3.423485 6.434745 6.396239 4.114418
>   3.687380 2.633139 7.356185 5.736677 4.462504 7.137034
>
> Class 4: 4.738094 21.736701  6.716363 10.306583  4.757640  6.265024

My code is as follows:

```
boxplot(hvol.concentration,class.3, class.4, ylab="8-OHdG Concentration (ng/ml)", main="Boxplot Distribution of 8-OHdG", ylim=c(0,25), pch=16, names=c("Control", "NYHA III", "NYHA IV"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boxplot(c(4.738094, 21.736701, 6.716363, 10.306583, 4.757640, 6.265024), plot = FALSE)$stats
##           [,1]
## [1,]  4.738094 <<== It's definitely there but the lower bound of the IQR is almost the same as min val
## [2,]  4.757640
## [3,]  6.490694
## [4,] 10.306583 <<== Upper bound of IQR == max val
## [5,] 10.306583
```

If you make the plot window bigger the grid size will be sufficient to see the lower IQR:

```
boxplot(
  c(4.738094, 21.736701, 6.716363, 10.306583, 4.757640, 6.265024),
  horizontal = TRUE
)
```

[image]